# In a pandas dataframe, how can I filter the rows based on a column value, do calculation and assign the result to a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have a dataframe of four people, divided into group A and B.
Now I want to filter out the group B, divide their Point by half, and assign the result to a new column named as 'Point_new'.

I am using the codes like the following

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Nick', 'Krish', 'Jack'],
        'Group':['A', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
        'Point':[20, 21, 19, 18]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Point_new'] = ''

df[df['Group']=='B']['Point_new'] = df[df['Group']=='B']['Point'] / 2
```

From output of the above codes, the Point_new column is not filled with the calculation result.
I wonder why is that, and how could I do it properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this , the key is to use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) -

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Nick', 'Krish', 'Jack'],
        'Group':['A', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
        'Point':[20, 21, 19, 18]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df.loc[(df['Group'] == 'B'),'Point_new'] = df.loc[df['Group']=='B','Point'] / 2


print(df)

    Name Group  Point  Point_new
0    Tom     A     20        NaN
1   Nick     B     21       10.5
2  Krish     B     19        9.5
3   Jack     A     18        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to set a value on a slice of a DataFrame. See more info here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Try this:

```py
df.loc[df['Group']=='B', 'Point_new'] = df[df['Group']=='B']['Point'] / 2
```

Which yields:

|  | Name | Group | Point | Point_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Tom | A | 20 |  |
| 1 | Nick | B | 21 | 10.5 |
| 2 | Krish | B | 19 | 9.5 |
| 3 | Jack | A | 18 |  |

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df = df.assign(Point_New = df[df.Group.eq('B')].Point.div(2))
```

---

```
    Name    Group   Point   Point_New
0   Tom     A       20      NaN
1   Nick    B       21      10.5
2   Krish   B       19      9.5
3   Jack    A       18      NaN
```